# How to turn .csv or .xlsx into multiple .txt files?

Tags: csv, xlsx

Essentially, I would like to have every row in an .xlsx file be its own .txt file.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes, there are numerous ways to do this. Please specify your language, fix your tags(don't use data tag as it explicitly says), add details to your question.

Comment: Sure; nearly always a way.  However, this site isn't intended to do the work for you.  once you decide on a path and start and run into problems, then post with specific examples and expected results.  We really don't want to do the work for you.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, excel macros can do this.

Here is some training material to get up to speed on it.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/training/get-in-the-loop-with-excel-macros-RZ001150634.aspx